# Using the table_id from __TABLES_SUMMARY__ in an SQL query to select tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently use the following legacy SQL query to check how many rows are returned in each table within a data set each day:

```
SELECT Date, table1, table2
FROM
(SELECT RowDate AS Date, Count(RowDate) AS table1
FROM [project:dataset.table1] GROUP BY Date),
(SELECT RowDate AS Date, Count(RowDate) AS table2
FROM [project:dataset.table2] GROUP BY Date)
```

This works fine, except that I would like the query to SELECT all tables within a given data set. I believe there should be a way to use the table_id column from this query to extract the table names within a data set:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
```

This gives me a table with meta data about all the tables within a dataset, including the table_id

The keen eyed will see that the second query is standard SQL, but I don't know the equivalent for Legacy (which I prefer to use)?

Can anyone provide a way to use the table_id in the first query and SELECT all tables (and name the Count(RowDate) column accordingly also)?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know the equivalent for Legacy (which I prefer to use)?

```
SELECT * FROM [project:dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__]
```